# Servlet: overwrite existing cookie

Tags: java, servlets, cookies

I have two servlets, one to perform registration of the user, and another one for log already register user. Each of this servlets send a cookie to user:

```
String username = request.getParameter(username);
Cookie user_cookie = new Cookie("userCookie", username);
user_cookie.setMaxAge(60 * 60); //1 hour durability cookie
response.addCookie(user_cookie);
```

(request and response are HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse types). After registration, user will be automatically logged into system. Now if a client logs into system (and receives a cookie), then the same client logout and register a new user (then receive another cookie, but as shown in the code, with the same name), user_cookie file, will be overwrite or not?

Comment: It will be, because it will be set for a new username. Cookie user_cookie = new Cookie("userCookie", username); explains it.

Comment: What a strange approach to store and check the logged-in user. Are you well aware that the client can manipulate cookies? And thus the client could just edit the username in cookie in order to get logged-in as a different user? And thus this whole approach is completely unsafe? Just make use of the session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it will be overriden.

### Old User

```
String username = request.getParameter(OldUser);
Cookie user_cookie = new Cookie("userCookie", OldUser);
user_cookie.setMaxAge(60 * 60); //1 hour durability cookie
response.addCookie(user_cookie);
```

### New User

```
String username = request.getParameter(NewUser);
Cookie user_cookie = new Cookie("userCookie", NewUser);
user_cookie.setMaxAge(60 * 60); //1 hour durability cookie
response.addCookie(user_cookie);
```

Note: New User Name Not Equal to Old User Name.